# Create a source target pandas dataframe from strings of flows

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Series of strings in the following format.

```
["s1, s2, s3, s4",... ]
```

I would like to create a two colum dataframe like this.

```
[[s1, s2], [s2, s3], [s3, s4]]
```

Currently im stuck on ho i can go from a Series to a dataframe.

Comment: Please give more details on your requirements and the data.  Give another element of the Series before the `...` and include it in the desired output.  Also, with the list you posted as desired result, it is not clear how the three elements map to a two-column DataFrame.

Comment: So shows us your code, so we better understand your needs. Its bit unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need list comprehension with flattening with function `window` for sliding window:

```
s = pd.Series(["s1, s2, s3, s4","s1, s2, s3"])
print (s)
0    s1, s2, s3, s4
1        s1, s2, s3
dtype: object

from itertools import islice

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822773/2901002
def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

a = [y for x in s.str.split(',\s+') for y in list(window(x))]
print (a)
[('s1', 's2'), ('s2', 's3'), ('s3', 's4'), ('s1', 's2'), ('s2', 's3')]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
    a   b
0  s1  s2
1  s2  s3
2  s3  s4
3  s1  s2
4  s2  s3
```

Answer (score 0):

With some formatting caveats, you can reshape the Series values, per [Reshape of pandas series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390224/reshape-of-pandas-series).

Note that I separated your s# elements into separate strings, and that the (2, 2) reshape only works for a series with 4 elements.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']).values.reshape((2,2))
print(s)

df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df
```

Output:

```
    0   1
0   s1  s2
1   s3  s4
```